# How to code ß (German "sharp S") in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, characters, german

I have an author called `Jörg Geißler`, whom I want to include in my BibTeX database.

I tried to use

```
Gei\ssler, J\"{o}rg
```

but this doesn't work correctly. I can't generate the PDF anymore. How do I type in the name correctly?

Comment: Did you try having `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and then simple write the name `Jörg Geißler`?

Comment: @Dror this isn't a good idea, since `bibtex` doesn't deal with UTF8.  In the same way that you put `\"{o}` you should put `{\ss}`.  (Otherwise how does TeX know whether the macro is `\ss` or `ssler`?)

Comment: Yes. Then the ß works but the ö is causing problem.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use an acute accent `´` as an apostrophe, but an actual apostrophe `'`. Assuming you have a German keyboard, press [Shift]+[#]. Wrong: doesn´t or doesn`t. Right: doesn't. This applies to German and English apostrophes alike.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Blockquote markup (`>`) is intended for actual quotes from a book or a document, not for code blocks.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to enclose the `\ss` macro in braces: (it's also a good idea to enclose the `\"` within the braces of the 'o'.)

```
Gei{\ss}ler, J{\"o}rg
```

Otherwise, TeX can't tell whether the macro is `\ss` or `\ssler`.  Usually macros can also be delimited by spaces in LaTeX, but this won't work in your bib file because the space is used by BibTeX to delimit parts of names.

So within your document

```
Gei\ss ler, J{\"o}rg
```

would render correctly as:

> *Geißler, Jörg*,

but used within your bib file the same input would be rendered by BibTeX as:

> *Geiß ler,  Jörg*

assuming you were using a lastname-firstname bibliography format.

Furthermore, if you used the form

```
J{\"o}rg Gei\ss ler
```

in your bib file, it would be rendered as:

> *ler, Jörg Geiß*

Comment: I'm surprised about the last sentence: Does `Gei\ss ler` not work? Spaces after macros are ignored. Of course `Gei\ssler` will not work. Anyway, braces around special stuff is never a bad idea with BibTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn: The surrounding braces are necessary to tell `bibtex` that it should leave the content (in this case a LaTeX command, but it could also be an uppercase word which shouldn't be made lowercase) as it is. For the same reason, it would be safer to replace `J\"{o}rg` by `J{\"o}rg.`

Comment: @Martin In bibtex the space will not work because it will interpret the space as separating two parts of the name.  So `Gei\ss ler, J{\"o}rg` will be output as "ler, Geiß Jörg"!  I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: @Alan,
using your Solution still doesnt solve my Problem.
In my Bibtex file i name the Author:
`author={R{\"o}{\ss}ler, Irene and Ungerer, Albrecht}`,
but in the Literature it strangely outputs this: > [Röß ler und Ungerer 2012] RÖSS LER, Irene; UNGERER, Albrecht:... also the citations in the text are incorrect: > (Röß ler und Ungerer, 2012, S.100)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#cite_note-2), *The capital ẞ was declared an official letter of the German alphabet on 29 June 2017.* However when I used `\SS` or `"S`, they ain't rendered as capital ẞ as I expected. Is there any solution?

Comment: Using `ẞ` and `ß` directly in *XeLaTeX* makes it fail to render them properly.

Comment: \ss is the easiest solution I believe