# Using geman ö and ß in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, natbib, characters, accents, german

in my Bibtex file i name the Author:
`author={R{\"o}{\ss}ler, Irene and Ungerer, Albrecht}`,
but in the literature list it strangely outputs this:

> [Rößler und Ungerer 2012] RÖSSLER, Irene; UNGERER, Albrecht:...

where the second RÖSSLER should also be RÖßLER

Update2: MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,oneside,numbers=noendperiod,headings=normal,appendixprefix=true,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Standardnormalverteiung ben\"otigt (\citep[S. 123]{mathe}).

\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{MeineBib}

\end{document}
```

MeineBib:

```
@incollection{mathe,
year={2012},
booktitle={Statistik für Wirtschaftswissenschaftler},
series={BA KOMPAKT},
title={Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung},
publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
author={R{\"o}{\ss}ler, Irene and Ungerer, Albrecht},
pages={83-136},
language={German}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess you are using the wrong document class. All options are related to `scrartcl` instead of `article`. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to code ß (German "sharp S") in BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26339)?

Comment: Yes i am using the answer that Alan proposed ...

Comment: Isn't the reason simply that there is no capital ß (Ok, I know that Unicode recently ratified it, but what do they know?).

Comment: If you are getting this output then you need to show exactly a small complete document that shows the problem.  Can you also paste the exact entry from your `.bib` file.  I suspect you have an extra space there, perhaps.

Comment: @Simifilm the extra space in the output is his problem, but to understand that one needs a full MWE ... something fishy here

Comment: yes... working on it... the bibtex entry is as follows >@incollection{mathe,
year={2012},
isbn={978-3-642-32256-3},
booktitle={Statistik f{\"u}r Wirtschaftswissenschaftler},
series={BA KOMPAKT},
doi={10.1007/978-3-642-32257-0_4},
title={Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung},
url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-32257-0_4},
publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
author={R{\"o}{\ss}ler, Irene and Ungerer, Albrecht},
pages={83-136},
language={German}
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to code ß (German "sharp S") in BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26338/how-to-code-ss-german-sharp-s-in-bibtex)

Comment: @user30652 You can [edit] your question when you’re providing more code. Also see the bottom of my answer at [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for a hint on how to include biliography MWEs. (And a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).)

Comment: As written -- you are using the wrong document class!

Comment: The posted `.bib` file contains a `~` after `{\ss}`.  This will give a hard coded space; it should simply be removed.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, i dont know where that came from... it solved the space issue... sadly the RÖSSLER issue in the Literature list still exists. @Marco im not sure how the document class is related to my problem... Still working on the MWE i think i messed it up ;)

Comment: @user30652 If you don’t want to have to type `ben\"otigt` every time, check out [Automatically change é to \'e – most convenient setup for accented letters?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97233).

Comment: thanks, i didnt know i could do that... saved me alot of frustration ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your entry. You are typing: `R{\"o}{\ss}~ler`. However the token `~` forces a space. So simple write: `R{\"o}{\ss}ler`.

Here the correct entry:

```
@incollection{mathe,
 year={2012},
 isbn={978-3-642-32256-3},
 booktitle={Statistik für Wirtschaftswissenschaftler},
 series={BA KOMPAKT},
 doi={10.1007/978-3-642-32257-0_4},
 title={Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung},
 url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-32257-0_4},
 publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
 author={R{\"o}{\ss}ler, Irene and Ungerer, Albrecht},
 pages={83-136},
 language={German}
}
```

The following options only work with a KOMA class. In your case it ought be `scrartcl`.

```
 numbers=noendperiod,headings=normal,%
 appendixprefix=true,bibliography=totoc,
 listof=totoc
```

Here a correct mwe

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,oneside,%
     numbers=noendperiod,headings=normal,%
     appendixprefix=true,bibliography=totoc,
     listof=totoc]%
{scrartcl}
\usepackage{natbib}                                        
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                               
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %Spezialzeichen in Tex-Code
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MeineBib.bib}
@incollection{mathe,
 year={2012},
 isbn={978-3-642-32256-3},
 booktitle={Statistik für Wirtschaftswissenschaftler},
 series={BA KOMPAKT},
 doi={10.1007/978-3-642-32257-0_4},
 title={Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung},
 url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-32257-0_4},
 publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
 author={R{\"o}{\ss}ler, Irene and Ungerer, Albrecht},
 pages={83-136},
 language={German}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Standardnormalverteiung ben\"otigt (\citep[S. 123]{mathe}).

\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{MeineBib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the second entry "RÖSSLER" is still with SS instead of ß    im new to this and im trying my best. sorry for any inconveniences caused by my poor forum skills :)

Comment: Anyway i found out that SS in the "small capitals" font is the correct translation for ß. I didnt know that :D. Thank you Marco for your answer.

Comment: @Sid officially there is no uppercase “ß” and also no small caps “ß” and “SS” is orthographically correct there. (Some fonts _do_ have uppercase and sc versions of “ß”, though...)

Comment: @Sid If you want an uppercase ß (ẞ – `ẞ`), you can use XeLaTeX and the packages `fontspec` and `libertine`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XMGvh.png

Comment: @doncherry Go, libertine! :) (The ẞ could be kerned a little bit closer to the ö, though... or the small caps could be spaced out more... or both...)