# How avoid "\T1\ss " as output from \immediate\write and get ß?

Tags: characters, output, filesystem-access, active-characters

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
... 
\newwrite\outfile
\immediate\openout\outfile=\jobname.txt
% aßbc is a replacement for a long german text-block, with many ß inside
\immediate\write\outfile{ "aßbc"}
\immediate\closeout\outfile
```

produces as file content:

```
"a\T1\ss bc"
```

but I want the string

```
"aßbc"
```

yes, I can replace `\T1\ss` with `ß` in a postprocess-step, but I like to know how to do it from LaTeX

Comment: May be `\unexpanded{ß}`? May be not :)

Comment: This topic might help you out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26338/how-to-code-%C3%9F-german-sharp-s-in-bibtex

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
\immediate\write\outfile{\unexpanded{"aßbc"}}
```

which, in my experiment with `ansinew` coding, writes out byte `"DF` for the es-zet, which corresponds to the entry

```
\DeclareInputText{223}{\ss}
```

in `ansinew.def`.

Comment: What if the string with es-zet becomes generated by some macros?

Comment: @sporack You're out of luck, I'm afraid. Do you really need the literal `ß` or just `\ss` is good?

Comment: Well at the end the (pdf)latex-run should produce an additional \jobname.txt file, which is an input-file for a later run of <br> `exiftool(-k).exe" -@ jobname.txt -charset Latin` <br> therefor in the written output I want no TeX-Code anymore :-)